# Avoid printing titles for empty bibliography when using BibLaTeX and pgffor

Tags: biblatex, pgffor

I am using `pgffor` and `biblatex` to generate yearly bibliographies with the title of the bibliography set to the year. How do I avoid printing titles for empty bibliographies in the MWE below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgffor}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @Article{Kalman1964,
        author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
        title     = {When is a linear control system optimal?},
        journal   = {J. Basic Eng.},
        year      = {1964},
        volume    = {86},
        number    = {1},
        pages     = {51--60},
    }
    @InProceedings{Kalman1963,
        author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
        title     = {Lyapunov functions for the problem of lur'e in automatic control},
        booktitle = {Proceedings of the national academy of sciences},
        year      = {1963},
        volume    = {49},
        number    = {2},
        pages     = {201--205},
    }
    @Article{Kalman1960,
        author  = {Kalman, R. E.},
        title   = {A new approach to linear filtering and prediction problems},
        journal = {Trans. ASME J. Basic. Eng.},
        year    = {1960},
        volume  = {82D},
        pages   = {35--45},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\yearcheck}[1]{
    \defbibcheck{#1}{
        \iffieldint{origyear}
        {\ifnumequal{\thefield{origyear}}{#1}{}{\skipentry}}
        {\iffieldint{year}
            {\ifnumequal{\thefield{year}}{#1}{}{\skipentry}}
            {\skipentry}
        }
    }
}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    \noindent \textbf{This works as expected, the title ``Books'' is not printed.}
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Conference Papers}]
    \end{refsection}
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type=article,title={Journal Papers}]
    \end{refsection}
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
    \end{refsection}
    
    \noindent \textbf{This does not work as expected, the title ``1962'' is printed even though the bibliography is empty.}
    \foreach \year in {1960,1962,1963,1964} {
        \global\yearcheck{\year}
        \begin{refsection}
            \nocite{*}
            \printbibliography[check=\year,title={\year}]
        \end{refsection}
    }
\end{document}
```

What I get currently is this:

[image: Compiled MWE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference in how `check` (`\defbibcheck`) and the `type` option filter bibliographies.

With `type` (and similarly with `keyword`, `category`, `segment`) `biblatex` can tell from the start whether or not the bibliography will be empty. This is not possible with `check`.

So one solution would be to try and base your filtering on bibliography categories. With some trickery those categories can even be created dynamically based on the data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\SoftDeclareBibliographyCategory}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@catg@#1}
    {\global\cslet{blx@catg@#1}\@empty}
    {}%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\blx@categories}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\blx@categories}{#1}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\SoftDeclareBibliographyCategoryX}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\blx@tempa{\endgroup
    \SoftDeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}}%
  \blx@tempa}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\categoryyears}{}
\AtDataInput{%
  \SoftDeclareBibliographyCategoryX{year:\thefield{year}}%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{year}}{\categoryyears}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\categoryyears}{\thefield{year}}}%
  \addtocategory{year:\thefield{year}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Kalman1964,
  author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
  title     = {When is a linear control system optimal?},
  journal   = {J. Basic Eng.},
  year      = {1964},
  volume    = {86},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {51--60},
}
@inproceedings{Kalman1963,
  author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
  title     = {Lyapunov functions for the problem of lur'e in automatic control},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the national academy of sciences},
  year      = {1963},
  volume    = {49},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {201--205},
}
@article{Kalman1960,
  author  = {Kalman, R. E.},
  title   = {A new approach to linear filtering and prediction problems},
  journal = {Trans. ASME J. Basic. Eng.},
  year    = {1960},
  volume  = {82D},
  pages   = {35--45},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \begin{refsection}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Conference Papers}, resetnumbers]
  \printbibliography[type=article,title={Journal Papers}, resetnumbers]
  \printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}, resetnumbers]
  \end{refsection}

  \begin{refsection}
  \nocite{*}
  \def\do#1{\printbibliography[category=year:#1, title=#1, resetnumbers]}
  \dolistloop\categoryyears
  \end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: Several different bibliography lists.]

---

Since the numbers in your lists are not going to be unique, there is no point in using them for citations anyway, so you could make your life much easier by letting the numbers be generated by a real `enumerate` instead of having `biblatex` try to generated citable labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\SoftDeclareBibliographyCategory}[1]{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@catg@#1}
    {\global\cslet{blx@catg@#1}\@empty}
    {}%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\blx@categories}
    {}
    {\listgadd{\blx@categories}{#1}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\SoftDeclareBibliographyCategoryX}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\blx@tempa{\endgroup
    \SoftDeclareBibliographyCategory{#1}}%
  \blx@tempa}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\categoryyears}{}
\AtDataInput{%
  \SoftDeclareBibliographyCategoryX{year:\thefield{year}}%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{year}}{\categoryyears}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\categoryyears}{\thefield{year}}}%
  \addtocategory{year:\thefield{year}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\theenumi}
     {\usecounter{enumi}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss[##1]}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Kalman1964,
  author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
  title     = {When is a linear control system optimal?},
  journal   = {J. Basic Eng.},
  year      = {1964},
  volume    = {86},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {51--60},
}
@inproceedings{Kalman1963,
  author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
  title     = {Lyapunov functions for the problem of lur'e in automatic control},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the national academy of sciences},
  year      = {1963},
  volume    = {49},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {201--205},
}
@article{Kalman1960,
  author  = {Kalman, R. E.},
  title   = {A new approach to linear filtering and prediction problems},
  journal = {Trans. ASME J. Basic. Eng.},
  year    = {1960},
  volume  = {82D},
  pages   = {35--45},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Conference Papers}]
  \printbibliography[type=article,title={Journal Papers}]
  \printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]


  \nocite{*}
  \def\do#1{\printbibliography[category=year:#1, title=#1]}
  \dolistloop\categoryyears
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is supposed to work ... But I am not sure it will work in any case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgffor}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @Article{Kalman1964,
        author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
        title     = {When is a linear control system optimal?},
        journal   = {J. Basic Eng.},
        year      = {1964},
        volume    = {86},
        number    = {1},
        pages     = {51--60},
    }
    @InProceedings{Kalman1963,
        author    = {Kalman, R. E.},
        title     = {Lyapunov functions for the problem of lur'e in automatic control},
        booktitle = {Proceedings of the national academy of sciences},
        year      = {1963},
        volume    = {49},
        number    = {2},
        pages     = {201--205},
    }
    @Article{Kalman1960,
        author  = {Kalman, R. E.},
        title   = {A new approach to linear filtering and prediction problems},
        journal = {Trans. ASME J. Basic. Eng.},
        year    = {1960},
        volume  = {82D},
        pages   = {35--45},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\newsavebox\myBibBox
\newsavebox\myBibBoxB
\newcommand{\yearcheck}[1]{
    \defbibcheck{#1}{
        \iffieldint{origyear}
        {\ifnumequal{\thefield{origyear}}{#1}{}{\skipentry}}
        {\iffieldint{year}
            {\ifnumequal{\thefield{year}}{#1}{}{\skipentry}}
            {\skipentry}
        }
    }
}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    \noindent \textbf{This works as expected, the title ``Books'' is not printed.}
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={Conference Papers}]
    \end{refsection}
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type=article,title={Journal Papers}]
    \end{refsection}
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
    \end{refsection}
    \noindent \textbf{This does not work as expected, the title ``1962'' is printed even though the bibliography is empty.}
    \foreach \year in {1960,...,1964}{
        \global\yearcheck{\year}
        \begin{refsection}
            \nocite{*}
            \global\sbox\myBibBox{\vbox{\printbibliography[check=\year,heading=none]}}
            \ifdim\ht\myBibBox>\baselineskip
            \printbibliography[check=\year,title=\year]
            \fi
        \end{refsection}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this trick, but the answer I accepted is probably the better way to achieve this.

Comment: Sure @Rushi ... I would chose the same answer...